# Microsoft Azure Media Player Start At Defined Time

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-media-services

I have just started familiarising the azure media player and need to achieve setting the video to a defined timeframe at load.The code I have used so far is as follows.The reference used in the application also as part of the question.

```
<link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
<script>
  amp.options.flashSS.swf = "//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/techs/StrobeMediaPlayback.2.0.swf"
  amp.options.flashSS.plugin = "//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/techs/MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-osmf2.0.swf"
  amp.options.silverlightSS.xap = "//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/techs/SmoothStreamingPlayer.xap"
</script>



@{
    var ContentUrl = ViewBag.ContentUrl;
}

<video id="vd123" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered">

</video>
<script>

    var myOptions = {
        //"nativeControlsForTouch": false,
        techOrder: ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "silverlightSS", "html5"],
        "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
        autoplay: false,
        controls: true,
        width: "640",
        height: "400",
        poster: ""
    };
    var myPlayer = amp("vd123", myOptions, function () {

    });


    myPlayer.src([
      {
          src: "src",
          type: "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml"
      },
    ]);
    myPlayer.currentTime(5);
</script>
```

[Set begin time of Azure Media Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002371/set-begin-time-of-azure-media-player) looked at this URL but not provided full code or not feeling any difference to what I tried?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [linked thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002371/set-begin-time-of-azure-media-player) there are two ways to achieve this depending on your specific scenario. If you want to start at a specific time because there is a preroll slate (or like content that you don't care for your user to see), you should use the dynamic manifests in Azure Media Services. This is the recommended method and is generally the main scenario.

Also, as mentioned in the linked thread, if you wish to have done specifically in the player (so that means the content is actually viewable but just want to start at a specific time), you should listen for the play or playing event and set the currentTime after that point.

A simple way to do this is directly after setting the source of Azure Media Player:

```
myPlayer.addEventListener(amp.eventName.play, startTime);
function startTime() {
    myPlayer.currentTime(5);
    myPlayer.removeEventListener(amp.eventName.play, startTime)
}
```

Comment: Hi Amit,Thanks for the reply.The scenario a user is watching a video and he paused the video and closed the page.At that time i am storing the current time in DB.The next time he visits the page i need to pause at the same time then when he clicks play it will start from that point.

Comment: Then the listening to the events is the way to go.